# How could a LinkedHashMap fail to find an entry produced by an iterator?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

Under what circumstances given a correct implementation of hashCode and equals() can the following code return false?

```
myLinkedHashMap.containsKey(myLinkedHashMap.keySet().iterator().next())
```

Comment: By "deterministic" do you mean "correct"?

Comment: it doesn't matter in this case because it's the same object, right?  So as long as 2 invocations on the same object produce the same hashCode this should return true.  But yes, it is also correct.

Comment: But "deterministic" doesn't mean "2 invocations on the same object produce the same hashCode". There's nothing *non-deterministic* about `ArrayList<T>.hashCode`, but see my answer...

Comment: Yeah, looks like a mutable field is changing.  D'oh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely scenario I can think of would be even though `hashCode` is "deterministic", it may be based on mutable fields.  If you change the fields used to compute `hashCode` after it's put in the `Map`, then you won't be able to find it anymore.

Edit: should clarify you 'usually' won't be able to find it anymore.  Occasionally it will still work since two numbers can still rehash into the same bucket.  This, of course, only adds to the confusion when it happens!

Answer (score 3):

Every hash algorithm I have seen is "deterministic", in that for a given set of input values, you get the same hash value.

If the hash code is computed based on mutable properties of the object, the hash code will change after it's in the hash map if any of those mutable properties are changed.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean by "deterministic", but any hash-changing mutation to the key after it's been inserted into the hash map could easily have that effect.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<List<String>, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<List<String>, String>();

    map.put(strings, "");
    System.out.println(map.containsKey(map.keySet().iterator().next())); // true
    strings.add("Foo");
    System.out.println(map.containsKey(map.keySet().iterator().next())); // false
  }
}
```

The hash code of `ArrayList<T>` is deterministic, but that doesn't mean it won't change if the contents of the list changes.

Answer (score 2):

1. If the `hashCode()` is based on instance attributes that are **mutable** and those attributes are changed after the insertion, the `hashCode()` call during the iteration will return something different. And the `equals()` should be based on these same attributes, it will be expected to fail as well.
2. When another thread has removed all the **next** items from an `Map` in the middle of an iteration, there will be no more `next()`.

I would not use the `hashCode()` values as keys, I would you the objects themselves.

Comment: doesn't matter if your particular instance you are thinking about doesn't use but one thread, your **question** asked when it might happen, that is one case it might happen.

Answer (score 1):

If your `hashCode` and `equals` don't agree with one another, this could return false.  For example, if the `equals` method always returns `false`, this will return `false`, since there isn't any object that would ever compare equal to the keys in the map.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check hasNext() first.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the first key in another thread between getting the first keys and calling containsKey.